# Inherited objects difference

Tags: java

```
class C1 {
....
}

class C2 extends C1 {
 ....
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        C1 obiect = new C2();

    }
}
```

Why can I make a C2 object out of a C1 one? What's the difference between   `C1 obiect = new C2();` and   `C2 obiect = new C2();`

Comment: See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Comment: Add a method to `C2` that isn't in `C1` and try to call it either way. You'll quickly discover a difference.

Comment: C1 obiect = new C2(); object will not be able to call methods specific to C2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tweaking your code a little:

```
class Animal {
  // ...
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  // ...
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Animal obiect = new Dog(); // A DOG (RHS) is ALSO an ANIMAL(LHS)

    }
}
```

NOTE:

If you point to a DOG and say that its an ANIMAL, it can only do what ALL animals do (general behaviour defined in ANIMAL class). It can sleep(), eat() etc. But it can't call bark() because ALL ANIMALS don't bark. I.e, by referring to a subclass instance using a superclass reference, you are limiting the access of all methods of the subClass i.e, you can access only the overriden methods.

Comment: Edited for further explaination.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you can do this, is because of Polymorphism, one of Object-Oriented principles.

The idea is that a reference to a base class (in your case `C1`), can hold an instance to any subclass (in your case `C2`). This allows you to decouple implementation from interface.

As for your second question, the difference is that when you declare the reference to be of type `C2`, you are committing to the `C2` implementation, whereas when the reference is of type `C1`, you can change the implementation to any `C1` subclass, or to `C1` itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
 C1 object=new C2();
```

This statement means creating class C2 object with the reference of class C1

This is mainly used for the object oriented principle `Method Overriding`. With the help of this, you can call an overriding method defined in class C2

Answer (score 0):

This is called **parent class reference child class object**. C1 is parent of C2 so it can be used as a reference to all its child as well as for object of it's own type. The basic difference is between

```
C1 obiect1 = new C2();
```

and

```
C2 obiect2 = new C2();
```

is that **object1** has no knowledge of child class(C2) methods and variables. So you can't access any method or variable od C2 using object1 except overrided methods. But you can access both parent(C1) and child(C2) methods and variables using  object2.

```
class Parent {
   public String name;
}

class Child extends Parent{
  public  int salary;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Parent parent = new Child();
    parent.name= "abcd"; // allowed
    //parent.salary= 12; // Not allowed
    Child child = new Child();
    child.name= "abcd"; // allowed
    child.salary= 12; // allowed
}
```